# How to show the title for the diagram of Seaborn pairplot() or PridGrid()

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns

    sns.set_style('whitegrid')
    %matplotlib inline

    sns.pairplot(df.dropna())
    plt.show()
```

I would like to know how to show the title for this plot? Thank you very much.

Comment: This isn't a complete runnable example. Add the smallest amount of dummy data necessary to actually generate a plot.

Comment: Unfortunately, the title appears somewhere in the middle of the plot, rather than on the top.

Answer (score 43):

answer provided by [ivandov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49594152/4831795) worked for me , and yes i also got the problem with extra spacing. one can simply use :

```
g = sns.pairplot(df)
g.fig.suptitle("Your Title", y=1.08) # y= some height>1
```

to achieve extra spacing adjustment

Comment: Adjusting the height with y > 1 makes the title disappear for me (it is raised above the plot's viewable area). Any suggestion to prevent that?

Comment: See [`suptitle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html) in the matplotlib docs for all available parameters. For example, fontsize, alignment options, etc.

Answer (score 13):

```
g = sns.pairplot(df)
g.fig.suptitle("Your plot title")
```

Since this is a super title for the overall figure, you may need to adjust the subplot parameters to include extra spacing on the top. Luckily if you're using `plt.show()` you can easily do that from the window that pops up before saving.

Comment: Can you include the code to perform the adjustments required to avoid having the plot title appear overlapping the plot?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to previous answers but with simpler code:

`sns.pairplot(df.dropna()).fig.suptitle('Plot title', y=1.05)`

`y` is optional kwarg to indicate where along the y-axis the suptitle will be created in fractional axis coords. Here, going a bit above 1 will add a vertical buffer to the suptitle.

Answer (score -3):

To make sure this is the main title of the whole figure, you should use:

```
plt.suptitle('This is the main title')
```

You may add a y value to add spacing from the top row figures like so:

```
plt.suptitle('Main Title', y=1.05)
```